# Does Parse's findinbackground freeze the app?

Tags: android, parse-platform

Does Parse's findinbackground freeze the app? I am looking for a Yes/No type of answer.

Comment: Not worked with the Parse API but if you are not getting a NetworkOnMainThread exception it must be doing it in a separate thread, if so then the answer is NO

Answer (score 0):

No, it makes the network call in a background thread. Maybe the issue is at your callback.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Probably theres a issue on your code.
You can post it here so we can take a look.